# Git alias cannot find bash script file although its in PATH

Tags: git, bash, path, alias, git-bash

I want to call a bash function from the git bash shell, using a git alias, so I made my .gitconfig look like:

```
[alias]
    jjj = "!f() { source "test_script.sh"; foo $@; }; f;"
    st = status
```

My test_script.sh is in

```
/c/Users/myname/scripts/
```

The test_script.sh file looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash 
function foo {
    echo "This is a test script, calling foo!!!";
}
```

My PATH looks like this:

```
/c/Users/myname/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/myname/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/cmd:/c/Program Files (x86)/Brackets/command:/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin:%APPDATA%/../Local/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/c/Users/myname/scripts:/c/Users/myname/AppData/Roaming:/c/Users/myname/scripts:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/c/Users/myname/scripts
```

What I get when running:  `git jjj`  is:

```
f() { source 'test_script.sh' && foo $@; }; f;: line 0: source: test_script.sh: file not found
```

This error is despite having the path to my test_script.sh file in my PATH env variable.
Note that when i run test_script.sh from anywhere I succeed to trigger the test_script.sh

**Q: How can i solve this, or better debug this? this is driving me banana sandwich**

**My setup is:**

- OS: Windows 10
- Git version: 2.11.0.windows.1

Comment: I don't "do" Windows so am not sure what's on Windows 10, but this error is characteristic of running the bash `source` command using `/bin/sh` which does not have a `source` command. You could make your alias `sh`-compatible, or run it with `/bin/bash`, on a Unix/Linux system. Not sure what you can do on Windows.

Comment: Can you run `source 'test_script.sh'` in git-bash? Does it work? If not — what is the error?

Comment: why not `{ source "/path/to/test_schipt.sh"; ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the absolute path of the file (because you want the alias to be reusable in a different context), you need to check what your PATH actually is.

Replace your alias with `echo $PATH; shopt sourcepath`

That will check both your `PATH` and if `source` is allowed to use it (see [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash): If the `sourcepath` option to the `shopt` builtin command is turned off, the `PATH` is not searched)

As seen in the comments, the PATH was not exported (so sub-processes like the one spawned by the alias, did not inherit said variable)

And adding it (`export PATH=...`) in the `.bashrc` was not enough.

Looking at "[Bash doesn't read `.bashrc` unless manually started](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94492/7490)" and [`bashrc` not loaded in `/bin/bash` shell](https://serverfault.com/a/747313/783), you need a `%USERPROFILE%\.bash_profile` sourcing the `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks for propsing a way to debug this. Having the git alias run this command shows me a PATH which does not include the folder that contains my script. and BTW shopt soucepath is 'on'.  what am i doing wrong ? how can i constantly add mt scripts folder to this weired "GIT PATH"?

Comment: Can you try the same alias after typing `export PATH=...` (your all PATH, including your script folder)

Comment: Yeah, having the git alias add the folder I want to the weired "GIT PATH" works. So for every alias that calls that script I need to export PATH and add my folder ? sounds bizzar, I can live with that, BUT I will be glad to know another way to constantly add my folders to this Git Path, instead of adding upon executing git command

Comment: @Mercury No: my point was to check if the PATH was exported (ie all processes will inherit it) or not. You just need to add that export in your `%USERPROFILE%\.bashrc`, in order for any bash process to take the right PATH into account. Including your alias.

Comment: the thing is that I am exporting and adding my folder in .bashrc, my .bashrc looks like: `export PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/guylevy/scripts`   and having that alone will not affect this GIT PATH, its like git does not pay any attention.

Comment: +1 for the great help, but still I cannot understand why git ignores my .bashrc (there i am adding my path to PATH). really wiered. I will go with the  adding the export each time I call the git alias. Thanks

Comment: @Mercury by default, the alias might go with sh instead of bash

Comment: @Mercury Try adding, for testing, a .bash_profile, as in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94492/7490 or https://serverfault.com/a/747313/783

Comment: Boom ! you nailed it ! it was the  .bash_profile that git always loads. and 
probably discards the .bashrc. man i wish i could give you another +1. problem solved

Comment: @Mercury Thank you. I have edited the answer to include the conclusion of those comments.